# SwiftUI @State is updated only once when put inside NavigationView (macOS app)

Tags: swift, swiftui

#### Problem

I've put a simple button that increments a counter inside NavigationView, but the application appears to update @State value only once; later clicks are ignored. Switching between NavigationLinks will cause the view to update, but why it does not automatically after the `counter` did change?

#### Facts

`otherView` works fine after I put it outside the Navigation View.

#### Code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var counter = 0
    
    var otherView: some View {
        Button(action: {
            counter += 1
        }, label: {
            Text(String(counter))
        }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).padding()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink("otherview", destination: otherView)
                }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            }
        }.frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 400)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `otherView` into a seperate SwiftUI view like this:

```
struct ButtonView: View {
    
    @State var counter = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            counter += 1
        }, label: {
            Text(String(counter))
        }).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).padding()
    }
    
}
```

Then in your `ContentView` call it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
       
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink("otherview", destination: ButtonView())
                }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            }
        }.frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 400)
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked, but after I replaced `@Binding` to `@State` in the `ButtonView`. Thank you!